# How to deal with different revisions of a class?

Tags: c#, class, object, namespaces, version

I'm currently building a test client that needs to send data as JSON over plan TCP to a server application. The protocol - besides other elements - consists of message objects. Right now, there already need to be two different revisions of the Message class. They do not relate to each other and have completely different properties.

Here's an example to get the idea:

**Protocol version 1**

```
class Message
{
    public string sender { get; set; }
    public int message_id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int priority { get; set; }
    public List<string> parameters { get; set; }
    public Message()
    {
        this.parameters = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

**Protocol version 2**

```
class Message
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int someotherid { get; set; }
    public List<string> data { get; set; }
    public Message()
    {
        this.data = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

These classes have nothing in common, they don't share a common base type or something. How would I organize these different versions if I still want to use both of them as `Message` in my code?

The only thing I came up with was using different namespaces, so that the first version exists in `MyProtocol.Rev1.Message` and the other one in `MyProtocol.Rev2.Message`. This would work and I can simply pull in the desired namespace in the `using` section, but it fells a bit static. Is there a better way?

Comment: Namespaces are the way to go and the different revisions should be static so it is perfect when it feels static. I also put the different revisions in separate libraries

Comment: You're right, that makes sense. I thought maybe there's some magic feature I haven't heard of yet, but namespaces will surely do the job.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like that

```
    Message message = new Message();

    var messagev1 = message.GetProtocol<IMessageProtocolv1>();
    var messagev2 = message.GetProtocol<IMessageProtocolv2>();

    messagev1.message_id = 450077;
    messagev2.id = 1000023;
```

To do that

```
   interface IMessage
    {
    }

    interface IMessageProtocolv1 : IMessage
    {
        string sender { get; set; }
        int message_id { get; set; }
        string text { get; set; }
        int priority { get; set; }
        List<string> parameters { get; set; }

    }

    interface IMessageProtocolv2 : IMessage
    { 
        int id { get; set; }
        int someotherid { get; set; }
        List<string> data { get; set; }

    }

    abstract class MessageBase : IMessageProtocolv1, IMessageProtocolv2
    {
        public abstract string sender { get; set; }
        public abstract int message_id { get; set; }
        public abstract string text { get; set; }
        public abstract int priority { get; set; }
        public abstract List<string> parameters { get; set; }
        public abstract int id { get; set; }
        public abstract int someotherid { get; set; }
        public abstract List<string> data { get; set; }
    }

    class Message : MessageBase
    {
        public Message()
        {
            this.parameters = new List<string>();
            this.data = new List<string>();
        }

        public override string sender { get; set; }
        public override int message_id { get; set; }
        public override string text { get; set; }
        public override int priority { get; set; }
        public override List<string> parameters { get; set; }
        public override int id { get; set; }
        public override int someotherid { get; set; }
        public override List<string> data { get; set; }

        public T GetProtocol<T>() 
        {
            return (T)(object)this;
        }
    }
```